# How to use Google maps api with webpack and typescript

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, typescript, webpack

I'm trying to use google maps api in my react app using webpack and typescript.

i've tried installing this package:

```
npm install googlemaps
npm install @types/googlemaps
```

Then in my app

```
import * as GoogleMapsAPI from 'googlemaps';
```

I get the following error

```
[ts] File 'c:/MyAppFolder/node_modules/@types/GoogleMaps/index.d.ts' is not a module.
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to import from "googlemaps". `google.maps` is a global variable declared in googlemaps/index.d.ts. So you can use `google.maps` in your code right away.

For example

```
const point = new google.maps.Point(0,0);
```

For more info about typescript module and namespace. You can follow this [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html)

Comment: This works thanks, however I still have a compiler error [ts] Cannot find name 'google'. Any idea how to solve it ?

Comment: On which line does it complain?

Comment: Everywhere I use the google namespace, however the code runs perfectly. See here https://imgur.com/a/hClLd

Comment: Ah ok, I think it's the IDE issue. I use PhpStorm, and it doesn't complain.

Comment: Yes I think you are right, I'm using VS Code. This problem is unrelated to my initial question. Thanks

Comment: After some messing around, I added the following line which seems to solve the problem: import {} from './node_modules/@types/googlemaps/index'